# Outlook adding whitespace below images or more padding

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, newsletter

So made a newsletter for a client, and just 1 slight little bug i have now on Outlook 2007,2010,2013,2016 assuming its cause these use Word as the rendering engine.

Basically i have a 2x2 grid each item being 50% so all sitting nice and snug but on outlook it looks like its either adding whitespace below the images or adding more padding to my text boxes [(see screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTgAp.jpg)

Here is my HTML for that section:

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td width="50%" background="#8f5470" bgcolor="#8f5470" style="padding-left:45px; padding-right:45px; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;">
        <h4 style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #ffffff; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 27px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: left; word-wrap: normal;">we take care of every detail</h4>
        <p style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #ffffff; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: left;">Everything from design and planning through to manufacturing and installation, and where required assisting you to appoint a builder for the required preparatory works.</p>
        <p style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #ffffff; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: left;">We are dedicated to making it as easy as possible for you.</p>
      </td>
      <td width="50%" class="show-for-large"><img src="http://aproposconservatories.co.uk/wp-content/themes/apropos_new/images/newsletter/detail-img.jpg" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; clear: both; display: block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="50%" class="show-for-large"><img src="http://aproposconservatories.co.uk/wp-content/themes/apropos_new/images/newsletter/benefits-img.jpg" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; clear: both; display: block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto;"></td>
      <td width="50%" background="#0599a8" bgcolor="#0599a8" style=" padding-left:45px; padding-right:45px; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;">
        <h4 style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #ffffff; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 27px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: left; word-wrap: normal;">we can offer benefits to our clients</h4>
        <p style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #ffffff; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: left;">In conjunction with Barclays we are able to offer a number of financial solutions, helping our customers stay in control of their cash flow.</p>
        <p style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #ffffff; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0; text-align: left;">As members of the IBGCo we offer consumer protection at point of sale and throughout the ten year guarantee period. Providing total peace of mind.</p>

      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: R u making responsive emailer or fixed?. This issue is because your image height is less than the text height in smaller screen.

Comment: Can u post ur entire code in fiddle?

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gzvfe8n3/

Comment: As far as i know you shouldn't use margin or padding if you want to make the newsletter adaptive to outlook because it uses old html 1.0 and css 1.0 and doesn't render these css properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added `mso-padding-alt: 0px 45px;` to parent td of the text.

Here is the working fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/6LgcnLka/

I have attached the screenshot of the ouput in outlook 2013

[image]